# Windows 7 выводит жесткий диск с данными Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7, ноутбук, dual-boot

На ноуте стоят 2 ОСи. Виндовс и убунту. Используя GParted разбил жесткий диск на куски. Установил win 7, она видит диск D: с убунтой как RAW. Можно ли его как-то скрыть? Подальше от греха...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Венде, в "Панели управления" ->"Администрирование"-> "Управление компьютером"->"Запоминающие устройства"->"Управление дисками" можно отключить отображение буковки на раздел.

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло. Только, уточню что эта операция скрытия в Винде называется удаление диска.